# JavaScript won't change image - Slider

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand why my slider won't work.

On the HTML page, I have first time, from the slider, and link to JavaScript.
In JavaScript, I have an array that includes 2 images.
Unfortunately, my slider doesn't work. The image won't change. It stays on the first one.

What might be wrong?

```js
var myImage=document.getElementById("slide");

var imageArray=["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"];

var imageIndex=0;

function changeImage () {
    slider.setAttribute("src", imageArray [imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex>=imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex=0;
    }
}
var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,2000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
  <head></head>
  <body>

       <img src="image1.jpg" id="slide"/> 
       
       <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never defined `slider`.  Replace `slider.setAttribute("src", imageArray [imageIndex]);` with `myImage.src=imageArray[imageIndex];`

Comment: You're using `slider.setAttribute`, but your variable is `myImage` - that's the problem.

Comment: Oh I see it now, I feel stupid. Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
var myImage=document.getElementById("slide");

var imageArray=["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"];

var imageIndex=0;

function changeImage () {
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray [imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex>=imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex=0;
    }
}
setInterval(changeImage,2000);
```